# Admob banner added programatically needs to be at the bottom

Tags: java, android, admob, banner

[image]

I have an advmob banner which was added programatically as bellow :

```
  public class MenuActivity extends Activity   {
    AdView  adView ;

    @Override   
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);


  adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a15013b6f790555");

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        this.addContentView(adView, relativeParams);
```

**When I run it the banner comes at the top of the screen , I want it to be at the bottom**

Here is the xml layout also:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/mainbackgroundipad">

       <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="74dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu1" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu2"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu2" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu3"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="63dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu3" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu4"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="83dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/menu4" />
    </TableRow>

              <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2">

 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu5" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu6"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu6" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu7"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="86dip"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/menu7" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu8"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu8" />
         </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu9"
            android:layout_width="60px"
            android:layout_height="80px"
             android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu9" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu10"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="56dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu10" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu11"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="65dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu11" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu12"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu12" />
  </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Comment: what does hierarchyviewer says ?

Comment: launch hierarchyviewer, take a look at that admob thing, make sure everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your XML file like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbackgroundipad"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu1"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="74dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/menu1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu2"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="59dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/menu2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu3"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="63dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/menu3" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu4"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="83dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/menu4" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu5"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/menu5" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu6"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="79dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/menu6" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu7"
                android:layout_width="60dip"
                android:layout_height="86dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/menu7" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu8"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/menu8" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu9"
                android:layout_width="60px"
                android:layout_height="80px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/menu9" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu10"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="56dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/menu10" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu11"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="65dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/menu11" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu12"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/menu12" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Change also the rule as  `relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);`

Also add:

```
//change  this.addContentView(adView, relativeParams); by 
        RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootview);
        rootView.addView(adView, relativeParams);
```

Comment: Nothing happened, still at the top

Answer (score 0):

```
Change your XML file like this:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/mainbackgroundipad"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu1"
                    android:layout_width="75dip"
                    android:layout_height="74dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu1" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu2"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="59dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu2" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu3"
                    android:layout_width="75dip"
                    android:layout_height="63dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu3" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu4"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="83dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu4" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu5"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu5" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu6"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="79dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu6" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu7"
                    android:layout_width="60dip"
                    android:layout_height="86dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu7" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu8"
                    android:layout_width="75dip"
                    android:layout_height="50dip"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu8" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu9"
                    android:layout_width="60px"
                    android:layout_height="80px"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu9" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu10"
                    android:layout_width="75dip"
                    android:layout_height="56dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu10" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu11"
                    android:layout_width="75dip"
                    android:layout_height="65dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu11" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu12"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu12" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/linear"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

And in java add your adview in the linearlayout.. Hope it must help you
```

Comment: Nothing happened, still at the top

Comment: Try to create your adview between the linear layout in xml. If it comes then you can call it in dynamically.

Comment: AdView adViewDraw=new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,"your key");
        linearAdViewDraw.addView(adViewDraw);
        AdRequest req=new AdRequest();
        req.setTesting(true); it must help

Comment: No_Rulz, i told him what the issues is about 15 minutes ago. This is expected behaviour, the issue is he is not using addView on the layout container. Hes using addContentView on the Activity

Comment: I didnt mean that comment in a negative way you know :D I was just saying, I think the part being missed is that he needs to add it to the RelativeLayout for this example to work :)